# How can I deploy a new ssh key to hosts after adding it in the maas admin account?

Tags: maas

I generated a new ssh rsa key pair.
I added the public key to the MAAS Admin "user preferences" => "SSH keys".

How do I push that new key to the maas nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think MAAS has the ability to push a new key to an already-deployed node. Are you sure there was not a single key imported to your account when you deployed the node?

Comment: so.... the answer is puppet?

Comment: Unanswered question: Are you sure there was not a single key imported to your account when you deployed the node?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, but in case someone still has this problem: If you add new SSH keys to your MAAS admin user, you can boot the system in rescue mode. This mounts these keys in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

You can then mount your root partition and copy this file to the respective home directories. After exiting the rescue mode and booting normally, the key should be available.